# Getting null pointer exception when trying to add data from sqlite to spinner

Tags: android, sqlite, android-fragments

I am trying to get a column of data from my sqlite database and insert each row as a different title in my spinner but i keep getting null pointer exception:

code from my sqlite adapter :

```
public List<String> getAllTitles() {
        String[] columns = new String[] { KEY_TITLE};
        List<String> leventList = new ArrayList<String>();
                Cursor titlecursor = MainDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null,
                null, null);// null pointer on this cursor.
                if (titlecursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    do {
                        leventList.add(titlecursor.getString(1));
                    } while (titlecursor.moveToNext());
                }
                return leventList;

    }
```

Code in my onStart() :

```
    mspinner = (Spinner)getView().findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
            mdatabase = new MainListSQLiteAdapter(getActivity());
mdatabase.open();
            List<String>lables = mdatabase.getAllTitles();
            ArrayAdapter<String> uadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, lables);
            uadapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            mspinner.setAdapter(uadapter);
mdatabase.close();
```

i am positive the sqlite database is populated.

**EDIT ( DATABASE OPENED)
logcat :**

```
05-07 11:26:37.798: E/AndroidRuntime(5579): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-07 11:26:37.798: E/AndroidRuntime(5579): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col 1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
05-07 11:26:37.798: E/AndroidRuntime(5579):     at android.database.CursorWindow.nativeGetString(Native Method)
05-07 11:26:37.798: E/AndroidRuntime(5579):     at android.database.CursorWindow.getString(CursorWindow.java:434)
05-07 11:26:37.798: E/AndroidRuntime(5579):     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:51)
05-07 11:26:37.798: E/AndroidRuntime(5579):     at com.wordpress.yourhappening.happening.MainListSQLiteAdapter.getAllTitles(MainListSQLiteAdapter.java:285)
05-07 11:26:37.798: E/AndroidRuntime(5579):     at com.wordpress.yourhappening.happening.Closest.onStart(Closest.java:57)
```

Comment: could be `mspinner` is null

Comment: well the null pointer exception is pointing to `Cursor titlecursor = MainDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null,
                null, null);` in the sqladapter. so yea  i guess mspinner will be null.

Comment: so the maindatabase is null, did u open your database and cursor ?

Comment: OOH yea i forgot to open the database, sorry. its giving me an IllegalStateException , now. ALso uploaded the logcat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line

```
leventList.add(titlecursor.getString(1));
```

to this

```
leventList.add(titlecursor.getString(0));
```